# What is the most efficient way of copy an array of ints in objective C?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, arrays, algorithm, ios

What is the most efficient way to copy an array of 1000 ints from one array to another in objective C?

This will be running on an iphone within some drawing code so its important to be as efficient as possible.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if the concern is efficiency, I'm assuming this is a C array of ints. If so, you can use memcpy().

For example:

```
int copyOfArr[4], arr[4] = {0,1,2,3};

memcpy(copyOfArr, arr, sizeof(arr));
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: I'm actually having a hard time finding good documentation on how to use memcpy() for copying arrays of ints. Any pointers?

Comment: THanks that does help - how would you copy subsets of the array (i.e. from StartIndex to endIndex)?

Answer (score 2):

If you are talking about a normal C array, then memcpy is the most efficient way. If you are talking about NSArray, then send a "copy" message.