# iOS how to copy/reference a C-Array?

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays

I have 3 arrays with ints (enums):

```
static int *openEnv[] = {INGMenuItemLogon,INGMenuItemSpace,INGMenuItemAppointment,INGMenuItemInfo,INGMenuItemSettings};
static int *closedEnv[] = {INGMenuItemLogoff,INGMenuItemSpace,INGMenuItemOverview,INGMenuItemAccounts,INGMenuItemTransfer,INGMenuItemAnalyse,INGMenuItemAppointment,INGMenuItemInfo,INGMenuItemSettings};
int *currentEnv[];
```

if the user taps on a button i want the `currentEnv` to change to the `openEnv` or `closedEnv`

```
- (void) tap
{
    if( closed ) currentEnv = closedEnv;
    else currentEnv = openEnv;
}
```

But this gives a build errors.
`openEnv` and `closedEnv` have 2 different sizes, what should i do to copy it? What can i do so that it makes a reference or copy to its static array?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4355556/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-of-copy-an-array-of-ints-in-objective-c

Comment: @rptwsthi - I don't think its the same

Comment: Those are not arrays of enums, they are arrays of pointers to ints.

Comment: Please revise your question. Are all tags really appropriate? At least decide on the used _language_!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have declared arrays of *pointers to int*. Correct would be

```
static int openEnv[] = {INGMenuItemLogon,INGMenuItemSpace,INGMenuItemAppointment,INGMenuItemInfo,INGMenuItemSettings};
static int closedEnv[] = {INGMenuItemLogoff,INGMenuItemSpace,INGMenuItemOverview,INGMenuItemAccounts,INGMenuItemTransfer,INGMenuItemAnalyse,INGMenuItemAppointment,INGMenuItemInfo,INGMenuItemSettings};
```

(without the star `*`) to declare arrays of int, and

```
int *currentEnv;
```

as pointer to int. Then you can assign e.g. `currentEnv = openEnv` so that `currentEnv` points to the elemens of `openEnv`.

Comment: +1 supposed that OP wanted to have an array of integers instead of array of pointers to integers :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
static int *openEnv[] = {INGMenuItemLogon,INGMenuItemSpace,INGMenuItemAppointment,INGMenuItemInfo,INGMenuItemSettings};
static int *closedEnv[] = {INGMenuItemLogoff,INGMenuItemSpace,INGMenuItemOverview,INGMenuItemAccounts,INGMenuItemTransfer,INGMenuItemAnalyse,INGMenuItemAppointment,INGMenuItemInfo,INGMenuItemSettings};
//int *currentEnv[];
int **currentEnv;

- (void) tap
   {
     if( closed ) 
        currentEnv = closedEnv;
     else 
        currentEnv = openEnv;
   }
```

Comment: how can i get an int out the array then, currentEnv[0] gives Statement requires expression of integer type ('int *' invalid)

Comment: BTW: I supposed you wanted to have an array of pointers, if you need an array of integers so do it like Martin R said.

Answer (score 1):

Just use: `int ** currentEnv  = <the array>`